# Using VLC capturing the video, and saving the frame as jpeg, how?

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu, vlc

How do i get from the video stream 1 frame and saved it as samp.jpeg (keep overwriting on the same file 1 frame), so that i can use it in my python canvas or gui rendering from that jpeg and also in browser.

Following test does not work with.

```
#!/bin/bash
ps aux | grep vlc | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9;
vlc -I dummy --no-audio --video-filter=scene --start-time=1 --stop-time=1 --scene-format=jpeg --scene-ratio=24 --scene-prefix=EXEC samp.jpeg vlc://quit
```

does not work

WORKS:

```
There is an entry for this at wiki.videolan.org/How_to_create_thumbnails : vlc C:\video\to\process.mp4 --rate=1 --video-filter=scene --vout=dummy --start-time=10 --stop-time=11 --scene-format=png --scene-ratio=24 --scene-prefix=snap --scene-path=C:\path\for\snapshots\ vlc://quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ffmpeg is an option, take a look at
http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video

I think VLC is the wrong vehicle for creating the image, but I guess one could come up with a solution based on the MJPEG streaming.

Comment: FFMpeg is not the way. Because the stream capture, only is compatible with VLC not with FFMPeg.

Comment: There is an entry for this at http://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_create_thumbnails : vlc C:\video\to\process.mp4 --rate=1 --video-filter=scene --vout=dummy --start-time=10 --stop-time=11 --scene-format=png --scene-ratio=24 --scene-prefix=snap --scene-path=C:\path\for\snapshots\ vlc://quit

Comment: i can have now the PNG files but they are like 1.001.png , 002.png 003.png, how can i tell to use onefile.overwriteme.png? Also it stop after few seconds. i want it never close itself unless i force it to.

Comment: The wiki lists --snapshot-path instead of ... prefix as an alternative. I haven't tried it, though: http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Play_HowTo/Format_String